# bmBit in BITMAP struct always NULL after using GetObjet() from LoadImage()

Tags: c++, bitmap

I am trying to load bitmaps that store in my file to my application. I do in in the following way

```
HBITMAP hbitmap = NULL;
hbitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,TEXT("F:\\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Projects\\test\\test\\bitmap1.bmp"),IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
BITMAP bmp;
GetObject(hbitmap,sizeof(BITMAP),&bmp);
```

In the bitmap struct, the bitmap size is correct as the following:

```
bmp {bmType=0 bmWidth=1920 bmHeight=1080 ...}   tagBITMAP
bmType          0          long
bmWidth         1920           long
bmHeight            1080           long
bmWidthBytes    7680           long
bmPlanes            1          unsigned short
bmBitsPixel         32         unsigned short
bmBits          0x00000000     void *
```

The problem is that the pointer to the bitmap which is bmBits always points to NULL (0x00000000). Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: does ((BITMAP**hbitmap)->bmBits equal to null ? I suppose it is. try LoadBitmap instead of loadimage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented behavior.  From the MSDN article for GetObject():

> If hgdiobj is a handle to a bitmap created by any other means, GetObject returns only the width, height, and color format information of the bitmap. You can obtain the bitmap's bit values by calling the GetDIBits or GetBitmapBits function.